# How to use the PIC16F628A's PORTA,4-7 as inputs?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, software, input, mplab

I'm working on a countdown timer and I want to use the MSN of PortA for my switches.
I'm using MPLAB. I can't use C to program the PIC because the collage taught us to program in decimal, and they will think I copied someone else work if I write in C. I've got the rest in order so far, but I'm having a hard time with this part.

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 2):

From [the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40044f.pdf), section 5.1:

> A ‘1’ in the TRISA register puts the corresponding output driver in a High-impedance mode. A ‘0’ in the TRISA register puts the contents of the output latch on the selected pin(s).

You'll have to set `TRISA<4-7>` to `1` (pseudocode):

```
TRISA |= 0xf0
```

This code ORs the `TRISA` register with `0xf0` and puts the result back in `TRISA`. Therefore, bits 4-7 are set after this, and your pins are configured as input, whilst the pins at 0-3 have an unchanged state.

In assembly, that would look like...

```
BANKSEL TRISA           ; switch to bank with TRISA
MOVLW  0xf0             ; Inclusive or 0xf0 with TRISA
IORWF  TRISA
```

Comment: It's better to use banksel to switch banks, instead of fiddling with the status bits.

Comment: You can do the OR and stuff the result back into TRISA in a single instruction. BANKSEL TRISA, MOVLW <mask>, then IORWF TRISA. I wouldn't switch back to any particular bank at the end of a code snippet since you don't know the banking needs of the following snippet.

Comment: @OlinLathrop good ideas, edited them in.